# Write / Insert Data into a Normalized Database Design Pattern

Tags: c#, design-patterns, normalization, database-normalization

I have an application that detects data changes of an AJAX driven WebBrowser control and then stores these transactions in a normalized database.

The normalized data model has 4, one-to-many keyed tables and when thinking about the write / insert, it occurred to me that there may be a time-tested design pattern for this.

Each data object can contain 3 data elements that would be repeated in a non-normalized or flatten database.

Would I need to search all three tables to determine if a record already exists before inserting a unique data element in a new table record from the transaction?

Is there a C# class in MS .NET, MFC or LINQ that;

1. simplifies the coding
2. improves the performance **or**
3. implements a best-in-class design pattern?

I've searched the pattern libraries and have not seen anything yet.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  I ran into a similar issue and used XML for the insert.

.NET has some awesome built-in XML functions, so it should (hopefully) be easy to turn your data into some kind of XML structure.  Once you have that, you can pass it into the database via a single stored procedure parameter for insertion.  Do all the checking within the stored procedure, rather than in your code.

Check out this article: http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2007/02/16/passing-lists-to-sql-server-2005-with-xml-parameters.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the input.  I've also looked into the OpenXML command in Transact-SQL.

Comment: The "key" challenge here is inserting data into child tables where a record already exists and the key to this record should be used when parsing the flattened (non-normalized) record into the parent table.  Further research indicates that LINQ does not support bulk inserts/updates.  One interesting technique describes loading the flattened array into a temporary table and then use Transact-SQL to parse the data into the respective parent and child tables.  Not being a T-SQL expert, I was looking for either code or patterns that have already been implemented and tested.